# Why will func closures sometimes delete its paramter name in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a function of two closures

```
testNetworkAvailability(reachableBlock:, unreachableBlock:)
```

But when I hit enter for the autocompletion of closure placeholder, the second one `unreachableBlock` will delete the variable name along with it and causes an error.

For example, if I open up this closure placeholder by hitting enter, it will look like:

```
testNetworkAvailability(reachableBlock: { () -> Void in
        <#code#>
    }) { () -> Void in
        <#code#>
    }
```

As a matter of fact, as I copy this function to stackoverflow, the placeholder for these blocks reads as `<#(() -> Void)?##() -> Void#>`. It is so strange as it should be `#() -> Void#` only, shouldn't it?

Why is this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the last argument is a closure, Swift allows you to omit the parameter name and treat it as an inline block.

```
autoreleasepool {
   // ...
}
```

See the documentation on [trailing closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102).

Should XCode's autocomplete prefer trailing closures than not is a topic for debate however.

Comment: Interesting, however, strangely, sometimes it does this `trailing closures` , but sometimes also, it will still autocomplete the block properly. So how to make sure my second closure can be autocompleted correctly?

Comment: I haven't explored how XCode decides which format it chooses, but understandably this is difficult for XCode because it depends on the context of your code. `autoreleasepool` as above, for example, is better as a trailing closure, while your code clearly needs the `unreachableBlock:` label for readability.

Comment: So I suppose the problem here is, although apple ALLOWS omission of parameter name, I don't think it should do it for you, right. Do you know how to disable it then?

Comment: Not really. But you can try poking around `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets` if there's any related snippet you can tweak.